# How much RAM does my motherboard support?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i5

I have an Intel® Core™ i5-4460 CPU@3.20GHz and an ASROCK-B85Mpro4 motherboard

Right now I'm having 12GB RAM running in it. My development programs are eating my memory and there are two free slot in my board, so I thought of upgrading my RAM. I planned for another 8GB, 4GB in each slot.

Will my system configuration support 20GB of RAM? Also how to find out how much RAM does a processor/motherboard support?

Comment: Maybe a strange idea.... but look in the motherboards manual?

Comment: 5s google search: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B85M%20Pro4/?cat=Specifications **- Max. capacity of system memory: 32GB**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too localized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [PC Part Picker](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/part/asrock-motherboard-b85mpro4), your motherboard supports up to 32GB of RAM:

> **MAXIMUM SUPPORTED MEMORY**
>
> 32GB

Therefore it seems that this upgrade could easily be done.